# Logging Into Yahoo! Fantasy Football with PowerShell & Invoke-Webrequest

Tags: powershell, yahoo, invoke-webrequest

Any suggestions for how to get the login request to work from PowerShell?  I am attempting to log in to my Yahoo! Fantasy Football League page to begin scraping some league data.  Can't get much further than the following, though:

```
$url = "https://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/1177458/players?&sort=AR&sdir=1&status=ALL&pos=QB&stat1=S_W_1&jsenabled=1"
$login = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable yahoo
$login.Forms[0].Fields.email = "****.********@gmail.com"
$login.Forms[0].Fields.pass = "*********"
$mainPage = Invoke-WebRequest $login.Forms[0].Action
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you, very much!
Eric K

Comment: You'd likely have better luck registering on their API, using your token, and pulling data straight from their exposed endpoints. They have some for League data.

Comment: Andrew -- thanks for your input.  I went ahead and registered for their API.  Do you know of anybody using javascript to access/pull league data from the Yahoo! Fantasy football API?  Wondering if I can use my strong-suit language to make this happen & pull into an AWS SQL Server database.